# Different number formatting on different Reporting Servers

Tags: reporting-services

I have an issue where two reporting servers have the same report but are showing numbers formatted differently:

This is a picture of the one that does it correctly:

[image]

And here's a picture of the one that does it incorrectly:

[image]

Notice that the "thousands" commas in this last one do not show for millions, thus behaving incorrectly. What causes this?

Like I said: this is the same RDL, and the same version of Reporting Services, no regional formatting, but on different servers.

Comment: What number format are you using, is it "n0" ? Also, are you 100% certain that the RDL's are exactly the same? Just be be sure, delete the problem report, download the working RDL directly from the server via the portal and upload it directly via the portal.

Comment: I'm using the options in SSRS. They translate to `#,0;(#,0)`

Comment: yes they are exactly the same, i deploy on both servers in parallel

Comment: Just delete the reports directly on the server and redeploy. I know some things do not get updated, such as default values, if you just update a report so if in doubt I always delete from the server first.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue. I solved it when I wrapped the field in the textbox in a `CInt()` or `CDbl()` and (this is important to do both) go to **Textbox Properties > Number** and make sure that it is a `Number` as well.